# Is there an equivalent of acpi=off of linux on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, acpi

I noticed that an old laptop I have here has broken ACPI hardware and it always shuts down whenever any OS (including vista, 7, 10, linux) tries to bring up any display resolution above the boot resolution. But it does work fine with acpi=off of linux kernel (it mainly breaks the shut-down feature) and I wonder if windows has a similar option (it has to happen at boot because it can't even go in the graphical environment!).

Answer (score 0):

To half-answer my own question this is probably doable with [NTLite](https://www.ntlite.com/), which allows you to customize any windows installation image before installing windows (I noticed it has ACPI related services in its options to disable). However I suspect even if one does manage to boot in that way it is questionable if it will keep booting that way especially after updates (because it's an undocumented way to install windows unlike linux).